# Header not shown in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Do I need to declare the header somehow or should self.navigationItem.title display the header in the table view by itself?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.items = @[@{@"name" : @"Take out the trash", @"category" : @"Home"}, @{@"name" : @"Go Shopping", @"category" : @"Home"}].mutableCopy;

self.navigationItem.title = @"What needs to be done";

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];
}
```

Comment: Is your table view controller embedded in a navigation view ?

Comment: You have to declare a header view for the table

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by:

Take a UIView for header in storyboard/xib.
Then in your .h file,

```
IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
```

And then in your .m file,

```
yourTable.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `navigationItem.title` will only work if your View Controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Call this method before presenting this view controller on screen to wrap your view controller in a navigation controller and present the resulting vc:

```
[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:myViewController]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is depend on you

if you want to set title as directly string for the whole page you can use

```
self.title = @"your title";
```

But if you want your own label with or image as a titleView you can create custom view(UILabel,UIButton,UIImageView,UIView and So On...) and set as below

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourCustomViewObject
```

if you want header on the tableView then you should have to 
create custom view in `viewDidLoad` and set `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = yourCustomViewObject` or you can take On xib as Hiren answered.

also if you have section(s) then also you can use one of the delegate of `tableView` i.e.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

along with

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

This will helps you.

Comment: If you want, you can see the source here: https://bitbucket.org/mlavender/a-little-to-do-app

Comment: I got message when I opened that link .... "Oops, you've found a dead link.
Use the links at the top to get back."

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a `tableHeaderView` property.

You just have to create a new UIView add a UILabel in it, and set the tableHeaderView with your new UIView.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //your viewDidLoad code
    // ...

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XPOSITION, YPOSITION, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
    UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XPOSITION, YPOSITION, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
    labelView.text = @"What needs to be done";
    [headerView addSubview:labelView];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```